# Defining a list in Python using the multiply operator

Tags: python, list, append

Recently in Python I have encountered this statement:

```
board.append([' '] * 8)
```

I have tried to search the Internet with Google to find some more information about this type of statement, but I can't.

I know *what* the statement does, but I do not understand *how*, in what manner is doing, that.

This is the first time I have seen the `*` operator used on a list. Can you please refer me to a place where I can find some more information about this type of statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can you please refer me to a place where I can find some more information about this type of statements.

Most of the relevant operators and methods are defined here: [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Specifically `s * n` is defined as

> `s * n, n * s`    -- `n` shallow copies of `s` concatenated

Here, `s` is a sequence and `n` is a number.

Thus, `[' '] * 8` returns a list consisting of eight `' '`.

`board.append()` appends the result to `board`, which presumably is a list (of lists).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what board.append() is doing, but the biggest problem for me was the * operator, and its use on the list. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
>>> L = [0]*10
>>> L
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

If you need to know how something works in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), look it up in [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/), or just experiment with it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Python docs. I have search there already, but it seems I wasnt very thural.

Comment: @depecheSoul: As dkamins says, it's hard to search for symbols, so don't feel too bad.